# How can I use other function variables?

Tags: javascript, global

How can I use `a` in `genTable`? It says that `a is not defined`

**JS:**

```
function colNum(){
    a=prompt(' The number of columns?');

    if(!parseInt(a))
    {
        console.log("Not number")
    }
}

function genTable() {
    table = document.createElement('table');
    table.setAttribute('id','tbl');
    tr = document.createElement('tr'); 

    for (var i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        var th1 = document.createElement('th');
        var text1 = document.createTextNode(i);
        th1.appendChild(text1);
        tr.appendChild(th1);
    }

    table.appendChild(tr);
    document.body.appendChild(table);
}
```

HTML

```
<body onload='colNum()'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `a` in `genTable`, either

1. Give `genTable` a parameter and invoke with it from `colNum`

   ```
   // in function colNum
       genTable(a); // a refers to the variable named a
   // ...

   function genTable(a) {
       // a refers to the parameter named a
   }
   ```
2. `var a;` in a closure that contains both `colNum` and `genTable`, and don't `var` over it in a descendant closure (you're currently not using `var` at all)

   ```
   var a;
   function colNum() {
       // ...
   }
   function genTable() {
       // ...
   }
   ```

Currently you can already access it, but this is because you've not `var`d it, which is a bad habbit to get into as it can cause identifier conflicts in future code